# How do I sync S Planner in Galaxy S5 with Galaxy Note 10.1?

Tags: sync, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, s-planner

I am trying to sync the data from S Planner in my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 to my new Galaxy S5. Sync Settings (**Settings > Accounts > Sync)** on both devices show that I have ticked all the boxes relating to my Samsung and Google accounts. Are there any additional steps I have to take in order to sync the data in the S Planner app?